# Show column text as link based on some condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid to show the value. Now one of my field based on some condition wanted to show text as link and that link should refer to javascript function.
Below is my code

```html
 columns =>
                                          {
                                              columns.Bound(r => r.RequestCode).Width(110);
                                              columns.Bound(r => r.StaffId).Width(90);

                                              columns.Bound(r => r.StaffName).Width(130);
                                              columns.Bound(r => r.Company);

                                              columns.Bound(r => r.RequestType).Width(90);
                                              columns.Bound(r => r.NoofDays);

                                              columns.Bound(r => r.TravelStartDate).Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}").Width(130);
                                              columns.Bound(r => r.TravelEndDate).Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}").Width(130);

                                              columns.Bound(r => r.SLADays).Width(90);
                                              columns.Bound(r => r.AdvanceAmount).Width(130);

                                              //columns.Bound(r => r.Installments);
                                              columns.Bound(r => r.Installments).Width(90);

                                              //columns.Bound(r => r.RecoveryAmount);

                                              columns.Bound(r => r.RecoveryAmount).ClientTemplate("<span  id='vatId'> #= VATAmount=kendo.toString((Installments == 0 ? 0 : AdvanceAmount/Installments), 'n0') # </span>" +
                                              "<input type='hidden' class='VATAmount'  value='#=kendo.toString( (Installments == 0 ? 0 : AdvanceAmount/Installments), 'n0')#' />").Width(130);
                                              columns.Bound(r => r.WfStatusDesc).ClientTemplate("<a href=javascript:jsFoo(\'" + "#: RequestCode #" + "\')>#: WfStatusDesc #</a>").Title("Expense Status").Width(110);

                                              columns.Bound(r => r.PaidAmount).Visible(false);
                                              columns.Bound(r => r.DutyTravelID).Visible(false);
                                              columns.Bound(r => r.StaffSeqNumber).Visible(false);


                                            

                                          }
```

so in wfstatusDesc column i want that if text is equal to Approve then show as link else simple text. and if show link then after click on that link should call a javascript function with passed parameter of request id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define template as function

```
<script>
function someFunction(data) {
    if(data.wfstatusDesc == 'Approve')
        return '<a href="#tips">'+data.wfstatusDesc+'</a>';
    else
        return '<div>Not approved</div>';
}
</script>
```

and then use it:

```
.ClientTemplate("#=someFunction(data)#");
```

Comment: Ok this is fine but how to set the text as link like <a href="#">data.wfstatusDesc</a>

Comment: I tried like this return '<a href="#"> '+ value +' </a>'; but not working.

Comment: I am able to get data and based on if condition setting the value as anchor tag but for first row it is showing undefined and all the row showing blank value.

Comment: If you have troubles only with first row that may caused some broken data from server. What what inside  `grid.datasource.data()` ?

Comment: Hey Layonez i change some thing like this  function SetExpenseStatusData(value) {
        //debugger;
        if (value == "Awaiting Approval" || value == "Approved") {
           
            return '<a name="lnkViews" href="#" style="color:Blue">' + value + '</a>';
        }
        else {
            return '<span>' + value + '</span>';
        }
    } in this first value was not submitted which i did not use any format that's why i was getting undefined now i put for that in span tag working fine thanks man. I am marking it as answer.